# Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable vs System.Collections.Immutable.Net40

Tags: .net, nuget, asp.net-4.0

What is the difference between these two NuGet packages?  Should I be using one over the other if I am creating a .net 4.51 project?  I've used the beta of the Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable in the past but just curious if one is going to be maintained better than the other or any pros and cons of using one over the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft officially maintains only one version of the System.Collections.Immutable assembly, and it targets .NET 4.5 and newer (as a portable class library). The first (and currently most recent) stable release of this library is version 1.0, and it is released as the [Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable/) NuGet package. Continued development on this open source library is part of the [.NET Core project on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx), and beta releases of version 1.1 appear in the [System.Collections.Immutable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable/) package.

If you need to target old versions of .NET, you currently have two options.

- [System.Collections.Immutable.Net40](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable.Net40/): This is a back-port of the 1.0 release to .NET 4.0. It does not include strong named assemblies, and I am not sure about its ongoing status.
- [Rackspace.Collections.Immutable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rackspace.Collections.Immutable/): This is a multi-target back-port of the current 1.1 beta release, currently going back to .NET 3.5. The assemblies include strong names, and the `[TypeForwardedTo]` attribute is applied to releases newer targets are drop-in replacements. For example, the build for .NET 4.5 is 11KB, and forwards everything to the System.Collections.Immutable assembly; if you have code referencing Rackspace.Collections.Immutable in a .NET 4.5 environment, you can include this stub and at runtime the .NET 3.5 or 4.0 code will act as though it was built against the 4.5 release.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.  I must be working on a pretty old project.  It's using the Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable 1.0.8-beta (Prerelease) which is why I was confused.  I'll just update my NuGet package of the Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable one then since from your answer this appears to be the more stable one.

Comment: @DanP Remember that stability here *primarily* refers to the API, not to whether or not the code behaves as expected. If you are developing a library which people outside your organization use, then the 1.0 release is probably a better choice. If you are developing a standalone application or internal library that outside users aren't extending, then the 1.1 release might offer performance improvements for you with very low risk.

Comment: Some time has passed and I assume that the [System.Collections.Immutable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable/) package should be used now? [Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable/) appears to have vanished or is perhaps now used for beta releases?